# Django image attachment FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, path

I want to generate a thumbnail of an attachment uploaded by the user to my Django site, but for some reason I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/tenant-2cadb939-306a-43f2-aa53-eb086a4f74b9/AssignedCampaign/2021-2/53676e7d-c95d-4348-a_581e4TM.png'
```

Although the file does exist.

This is the code I'm using:

```
if a.attachment:
       # get path of attachment without the attachment name
       cache_path = a.full_path.replace('/'+a.full_path.split('/')[-1], '') + '/preview_cache'
       
       log.info('>>>>>>>>>> %s', cache_path)
       
       preview_manager = PreviewManager(cache_path, create_folder=True)
       preview = preview_manager.get_jpeg_preview(a.full_path, width=100, height=200)
```

Comment: does the file exist?

Comment: yes.. it's getting the full path of it and says it does not exist

Comment: @Sam- Can you log how the full path looks like? A full path to me is something like this
127.0.0.1:8000/app/static/images/t.png

Comment: @SDRJ I do not think this is the case. I usually access my files using this path

Comment: @SDRJ That would be a URL for accessing it through the web, rather than directly on the server's filesystem.

Comment: @CrazyChucky- Got it. I wasn't clear on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do is to give the absolute path of the file